# Add appointment to Outlook calendar in Windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-8, outlook, windows-8.1

Is there a way to add an appointment to an Outlook calendar that is hosted on a private exchange server via Windows 8.1 store app?

From my understanding, I would be able to do so via [Appointments API](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/03/13/build-apps-that-connect-with-people-and-calendar-part-2-appointments/) and have the Calendar app connected to the private exchange server. Is there a way to do so without using the Calendar app? Do any versions of Outlook it's self (say, 2013 even?) actually subscribe to the Appointments API?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the required task using EWS. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.